# How to map state code from one csv file to state name in another csv file in python?

Tags: python, csv, file-io, mapping

I have one `csv` file, `csv_file.csv`, which had multiple records for each state and the state is identified with an id. The sample looks like:

```
state_id,year,value
01,2012,8.0
01,2012,8.1
01,2012,8.0
01,2012,7.7
01,2013,7.3
01,2013,7.0
01,2013,7.0
```

I want to convert the `state_id` in above dataset to corresponding `state_name` and write the records into another `csv` file,`output.csv`, so that for each state all the `value` fields come in one row and the output becomes:

```
Alabama,8.0,8.1,8.0,7.7,7.3,7.0,7.0
Alaska,8.1,8.1,8.0,7.4,7.25,7.6,7.5
```

For doing the mapping I have another `csv` file, `state.csv`, with the mapping details:

```
state_id,state_name
01,Alabama
02,Alaska
04,Arizona
05,Arkansas
06,California
08,Colorado
09,Connecticut
```

I wrote this code but this only seems to convert only 4 records(the top 4 records for `state_id` `01` and `year` `2012`) of the `csv_file.csv` as when I open the `Output.csv` I see only 4 records and that too for them the `value` field is repeated. My current code is:

```
reader_csv = csv.reader(open('csv_file.csv', 'rb'))
reader_state = csv.reader(open('states.csv', 'rb'))
file_write = open('Output.csv', 'a')
writer = csv.writer(file_write)

for line in reader_csv:
    for states in reader_state:
        if line[0] == states[0]:
           print line[0]+'='+states[1]
           writer.writerow([states[1]]+[line[1]]+[line[2]])
           break

file_write.close()
```

What is the mistake I am doing here and how can I do the mapping to change `state_id` to `state_name`?

Comment: Lets says a states appear from line 1 to 5 in csv_file. Your current code will read the states_csv from line 1 to 5 aswell (although you only wanted him to read the line 1 of states_csv). You will be "loosing" 4 states. I'm coding a solution right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my approach: For the *state.csv*, convert that into a look-up dictionary, then read the input, translate, write:

```
import csv

with open('state.csv', 'rb') as f:
    id2name = dict(csv.reader(f))

with open('csv_file.csv', 'rb') as ifile, open('output.', 'wb') as ofile:
    reader = csv.reader(ifile)
    writer = csv.writer(ofile)

    for state_id, year, value in reader:
        state = id2name[state_id]
        writer.writerow([state, year, value])
```

## Update

Update the code to write all the values on the same line. This solution makes use of the `itertools.groupby` function, which we group the records by the first field. The output will not have the header.

```
import csv
from itertools import groupby

with open('state.csv', 'rb') as f:
    id2name = dict(csv.reader(f))

with open('csv_file.csv', 'rb') as ifile, open('output.csv', 'wb') as ofile:
    reader = csv.reader(ifile)
    next(reader)  # skip the header
    writer = csv.writer(ofile)

    # Group by the state_id, which is the first field (record[0])
    group_by_state_id = groupby(reader, lambda record: record[0])
    for state_id, record_group in group_by_state_id:
        state = id2name[state_id]
        values = [value for state_id, year, value in record_group]
        writer.writerow([state] + values)
```

## Update 2

If your system has `sqlite3` installed (My Mac comes with it pre-installed), then the following script will get the desired result. Be sure to remove the headers from your csv files.

```
-- script.sql

.mode csv

CREATE TABLE state (sid TEXT, name TEXT);
.import state.csv state

CREATE TABLE raw (sid TEXT, year INT, value REAL);
.import csv_file.csv raw

SELECT state.name, group_concat(raw.value)
FROM state, raw
WHERE state.sid = raw.sid
GROUP BY state.name;
```

To use it:

```
$ sqlite3 < script.sql > output.csv
```

Comment: How would I write to the output file if say I want to write all records for each state in one row. So for example right now there will be 12 records for state Alabama. What if I want to write all the value in one row so that output file has one records for Alabama followed by the all the values for that state? I have updated my post above as well.

Comment: @JasonDonnald are the rows sorted by state_id?

Answer (score 1):

You should store your states unique identifiers in a dictionary. Then, access the values of that object for each line of `csv_file.csv`.

```
import csv

reader_csv = csv.reader(open('csv_file.csv', 'r')) # no b flag for python3
file_write = open('output.csv', 'a')
writer = csv.writer(file_write)

# Dictionary construction
with open('states.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    states_dict = {rows[0]:rows[1] for rows in reader}

# File writing
for line in reader_csv:
    writer.writerow([states_dict[line[0]]]+[line[1]]+[line[2]])
file_write.close()
```

Comment: How would I write to the output file if say I want to write all records for each state in one row. So for example right now there will be 12 records for state Alabama. What if I want to write all the value in one row so that output file has one records for Alabama followed by the all the values for that state? I have updated my post above as well.

Comment: Well, thats another question then... I was answering the original one.

Comment: I apologize for changing the output format. I didn't realize that until I made the update to my code based on your suggestion

Comment: Besides, you must know that you are actually loosing information in that new output format, because you are not storing the year.

Comment: actually year field is not important for me in my further processing as the order of the values will correspond to the year

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

with open('state.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    states = {row.get('state_id'): row.get('state_name') for row in reader}

with open('csv_file.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

    with open('output.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
        fieldnames = ['state_name', 'year', 'value']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()

        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow({'state_name': states.get(row.get('state_id')), 'year': row.get('year'), 'value': row.get('value')})
```